# getting last n items from queue

Tags: python, queue

everything I see is about lists but this is about `events = queue.queue()`
which is a queue with objects that I want to extract, but how would I go about getting the last N elements from that queue?

Comment: You mean the **first** N elements? You can't pop elements from the end of a `queue` (unless you are using `deque`)

Answer (score 5):

By definition, you can't.

What you can do is use a loop or a comprehension to `get` the **first** (you can't `get` from the end of a `queue`) N elements:

```
N = 2
first_N_elements = [my_queue.get() for _ in range(N)]
```

Answer (score 1):

If you're multi-threading, "the last N elements from that queue" is undefined and the question doesn't make sense.

If there is no multi-threading, it depends on whether you care about the other elements (not the last N).

If you don't:

```
for i in range(events.qsize() - N):
    events.get()
```

after that, get N items

If you don't want to throw away the other items, you'll just have to move everything to a different data structure (like a list). The whole point of a queue is to get things in a certain order.

Answer (score 0):

Though this was years ago, it bears mentioning that there is a method, which depends on the queue type you need.  If the latest entries to the queue are your concern then use a [Last-In-First-Out Queue](https://docs.python.org/3/library/queue.html#queue.LifoQueue). Opposite of the standard `queue`, which is First-In-First-Out. Please give larger examples.  With the little info given, here's how you get the last `N` elements from a LIFO queue

```
from queue import LifoQueue, Empty
events = LifoQueue()

# Wait for queue to be loaded with N events
N = 5
while N:
  try:
    event = events.get_nowait()
  except Empty:
    break
  # process event
  N-=1
```

You should handle the case where the queue is `Empty` in this case exit the loop and do not attempt to process.