# PyQt5 QThread is run on same thread as GUI thread

Tags: python, multithreading, qt, pyqt, python-3.11

I was attemtping to load thumbnails for QPushButtons on the side, so I created a thread for every image to load (there are only a handful of them for now). I based this code on https://realpython.com/python-pyqt-qthread/.

```
class Worker(QObject):
    finished = pyqtSignal(QIcon)

    def run(self, path: str):
        import threading
        logging.debug(f'Worker started at {(t1 := time.time())} seconds on thread {threading.get_ident()}')
        icon = QIcon
        icon.addFile(path)
        logging.debug(f'Worker finished @ {time.time()} seconds, {(time.time() - t1):.3} seconds later')
        self.finished.emit(icon)

# Step 2: Create a QThread object
self.thread = QThread()
# Step 3: Create a worker object
self.worker = Worker()
# Step 4: Move worker to the thread
self.worker.moveToThread(self.thread)
# Step 5: Connect signals and slots
self.thread.started.connect(lambda: self.worker.run(self.thumbnail_path))
self.worker.finished.connect(self.thread.quit)
self.worker.finished.connect(self.set_icon)  # basically lambda icon: a_btn.setIcon(icon)
self.worker.finished.connect(self.worker.deleteLater)
self.thread.finished.connect(self.thread.deleteLater)
# Step 6: Start the thread
logging.debug(f'Thread started at {(t1 := time.time())} seconds')
self.thread.start(priority=0)
```

I was expecting to see parallel execution (4 core / 8 thread CPU), but according to the logs, the thread IDs are identical:

```
2023-05-14T13:27:04 Thread started at 1684063624.1749578 seconds
2023-05-14T13:27:04 Thread started at 1684063624.3233523 seconds
2023-05-14T13:27:04 Thread started at 1684063624.3353844 seconds
2023-05-14T13:27:04 Thread started at 1684063624.5469468 seconds
2023-05-14T13:27:04 Thread started at 1684063624.7655282 seconds
2023-05-14T13:27:06 Widget setup completed at 1684063626.6284823 seconds
2023-05-14T13:27:06 Worker started at 1684063626.6485348 seconds on thread 10100
2023-05-14T13:27:06 Worker finished @ 1684063626.6585634 seconds, 0.01 seconds later
2023-05-14T13:27:06 Worker started at 1684063626.6585634 seconds on thread 10100
2023-05-14T13:27:06 Worker finished @ 1684063626.8139749 seconds, 0.155 seconds later
2023-05-14T13:27:06 Worker started at 1684063626.814978 seconds on thread 10100
2023-05-14T13:27:06 Worker finished @ 1684063626.8250043 seconds, 0.01 seconds later
2023-05-14T13:27:06 Worker started at 1684063626.826007 seconds on thread 10100
2023-05-14T13:27:07 Worker finished @ 1684063627.0385983 seconds, 0.213 seconds later
2023-05-14T13:27:07 Worker started at 1684063627.0395803 seconds on thread 10100
2023-05-14T13:27:07 Worker finished @ 1684063627.2581596 seconds, 0.219 seconds later
```

The files to be loaded range from 300kb to 50MB, and are stored on a 7200RPM HDD.

What might cause this behaviour?

I am using PyCharm 2022 Professional, Python 3.11, Windows 10.

Comment: Please provide a [mcve].  Also note that direct access to GUI elements such as `QIcon` is not supported on any thread other than that on which `main` is running.

Comment: You're making a lot of wrong assumptions. First of all "I was expecting to see parallel execution” is wrong because multithreading in python is **not** real concurrency, and that's due to the GIL. Then, the thread IDs you're using are not a reliable reference (as also pointed out in [the documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/library/threading.html#threading.get_ident)). Unfortunately your code is incomplete and invalid, and without a proper [mre] we cannot really validate your hypothesis. Finally, QIcon is not reentrant and creating them in a separate thread is unsupported.

Comment: These are exactly what I was looking for. If you posted these in an answer, I might have even accepted it because, well, of exactly what you said.
So, @musicamante, how am I supposed to load images on the side in Qt? Are there mechanisms for what I'm trying to achieve?

Comment: As said, without a proper MRE, we cannot provide reliable answers. This is important because you may as well be correct in your assumption due to the fact that you're using lambdas. That said, there are various alternatives for mass loading of images, but it depends on the needs and each case is different. Consider, though, that QImages *can* be created in external threads, and you could eventually create a *single* thread to queue image loading, and emit QImages in a custom signal, which you can then convert to QIcons in the main thread.

Comment: threading.get_ident()

    Return the ‘thread identifier’ of the current thread. This is a nonzero integer. Its value has no direct meaning; it is intended as a magic cookie to be used e.g. to index a dictionary of thread-specific data. Thread identifiers may be recycled when a thread exits and another thread is created., try make thethread run for longer time i.e. time.sleep()

Comment: @musicmante I can only create a MRE tomorrow. Do you think I should update this question, or create a new one?

Comment: @pippo1980 Thank you, I looked at the docs and it was indeed correct. It was a blind copy from another SO thread, so I assumed it was what I was looking for. What should I use instead?

Comment: no idea was just shooting in the dark ;-) try to see if you can get the total number of threads running at the same time ? or ask @musicamante : sure he knows better reputation 39,496 pyQt5  1,382

Comment: @Anaverageguy , if you make another question , just post the link here, I am following this question. To me its like you need to create a queques for each file loading but not sure if there is something like QTQueque and again dont know if lambda goes well with QtThreads

Comment: @Anaverageguy No, just [edit] this question and add the new code. Ensure that it's properly formatted by checking the post preview before submitting: we must be able to copy, paste and run the code without any substantial modification.

Comment: maybe solution is using https://www.pythonguis.com/tutorials/multithreading-pyqt-applications-qthreadpool/    QThreadpool

Comment: So using the QThread class to manage worker threads has two main challenges:

Determine the ideal number of threads for the application based on the number of CPU cores.
Reuse and recycle the threads as much as possible.
Fortunately, PyQt has QThreadPool class that solves these challenges for you. The QThreadPool class is often used with the QRunnable class.

Comment: see here : https://stackoverflow.com/a/74962048/9877065  https://docs.python.org/3/library/queue.html#queue.LifoQueue  --->  In a FIFO queue, the first tasks added are the first retrieved. In a LIFO queue, the most recently added entry is the first retrieved (operating like a stack).

Comment: @G.M. and @musicamante, FYI, a ```QIcon``` can be safely passed between threads using signals, as [the reference](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/threads-modules.html#threads-and-implicitly-shared-classes) says.

Comment: @relent95 With all due respect I don't think that's what the link says at all -- the link is referring to Qt's implicitly shared data types in general.  `QIcon` uses `QPixmap` internally and any attempt to create or write to a `QPixmap` on any thread other than that on which `main` is running is unsupported.

Comment: @G.M., that's quite an old knowledge. Nowadays, the ```QPixmap```(and also ```QIcon```) can be used in a worker thread on most platforms. [The Qt6 reference](https://doc.qt.io/qt-6/threads-modules.html#painting-in-threads) says that. [The Qt5 reference](https://doc.qt.io/qt-6/threads-modules.html#painting-in-threads) says "is not supported", but it is actually supported in most platforms. For example, you can see that from [the source](https://github.com/qt/qtbase/blob/v5.12.8/src/plugins/platforms/windows/qwindowsintegration.cpp#L295) for Windows.

Answer (score 1):

It's because you didn't give Qt a hint for determining a correct thread affinity when you called `self.thread.started.connect(lambda: ...)`. You should use a method(or a slot) of the `Worker`. But the `Worker.run()` has an argument(`path`) and you cannot connect it to the `QThread.started` signal.

If you don't mind using an instance attribute, do like this.

```
...
class Worker(QObject):
    ...
    def run(self):
        ...
        icon = QIcon()
        icon.addFile(self.path)
        ...
...
self.worker.path = self.thumbnail_path
self.thread.started.connect(self.worker.run)
...
```

If you want to keep the method signature, do like this.

```
...
class Worker(QObject):
    def post(self, func):
        # This can be called in the main thread.
        e = QEvent(QEvent.User)
        e.func = func
        # This is thread-safe.
        QApplication.postEvent(self, e)
    def customEvent(self, e):
        # This will be called in the worker thread.
        e.func()
    ...
    def run(self, path: str):
        ...
...
self.thread.started.connect(lambda: self.worker.post(
    lambda: self.worker.run(self.thumbnail_path)))
```

As a side note, you can safely pass `QIcon` objects between threads using signals in most platforms, unlike what others said in the comments on the question. (See [the detail](https://doc.qt.io/qt-6/threads-modules.html#threads-and-implicitly-shared-classes) if you are interested.)

Comment: I have not tested this yet. What is SO's standard, should I accept this as answer now, or should I wait and test things out and verify the result before?

Comment: would be best for me to have a working MRE to be able to check it against the original question that is not an MRE too

Comment: @Anaverageguy, you are free to accept an answer at any time. In my opinion, it would be good to check the answer before accepting it.

Comment: @pippo1980, because it's an answer, it doesn't need to provide a MRE. Personally I like a minimalistic pseudo code showing only important parts, because it's fast to read and understand a summary.

Comment: would icon = QIcon() in your first eample be on the run method of the worker before icon.addFile(self.path) or in the main Thread ??

Comment: @pippo1980, of course, it's good to be in the ```run()``` method. A ```QIcon``` object can be created in any thread. See [the reference](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/threads-modules.html#threads-and-implicitly-shared-classes). I updated the example code.

Comment: would be this an answer too https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74348042/how-to-assign-variables-to-worker-thread-in-python-pyqt5 ??

Comment: @pippo1980, yes, using the ```postEvent()``` is one way of passing data to a worker thread.

Answer (score 1):

OK, while revising all my (very poor knowledge ) on PyQt and QThreads I ended up with 3 answers, carrying a minimal reproducible example.

First one is based on first answer, in this same post, by @relent95, https://stackoverflow.com/a/76296571/9877065 , code :

```
import sys

import logging

import threading

# from time import sleep

import time

from PyQt5.QtCore import QObject, QThread, pyqtSignal, Qt

from PyQt5.QtGui import QIcon

from PyQt5.QtWidgets import (
    QApplication,
    QLabel,
    QMainWindow,
    QPushButton,
    QVBoxLayout,
    QWidget,
)


logger = logging.getLogger("test")
logger.setLevel(level=logging.DEBUG)

logFileFormatter = logging.Formatter(
    fmt=f"%(levelname)s %(asctime)s (%(relativeCreated)d) \t %(pathname)s F%(funcName)s L%(lineno)s - %(message)s",
    datefmt="%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S",
)

console = logging.StreamHandler()
console.setLevel(logging.DEBUG)
logger.addHandler(console)


class Worker(QObject):
    finished = pyqtSignal(QIcon)

    def run(self):
        import threading
        logger.debug(
            f'Worker started at {(t1 := time.time())} seconds on thread {threading.get_ident()}')
        icon = QIcon()
        icon.addFile(self.path)
        logger.debug(
            f'Worker finished @ {time.time()} seconds, {(time.time() - t1):.3} seconds later')
        self.finished.emit(icon)


class MyClass(QObject):

    # All QObjects receive a parent argument (default to None)
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super(MyClass, self).__init__(parent)   # Call parent initializer.

        self.thumbnail_path = 'test.png'

        # Step 2: Create a QThread object
        self.thread = QThread()
        # Step 3: Create a worker object
        self.worker = Worker()

        self.worker.path = self.thumbnail_path

        # Step 4: Move worker to the thread
        self.worker.moveToThread(self.thread)

        logger.debug(
            f'self.thread.isRunning() : {self.thread.isRunning()}, on thread {threading.get_ident()}')

        # Step 5: Connect signals and slots
        # self.thread.started.connect(lambda: self.worker.run(self.thumbnail_path))

        self.thread.started.connect(self.worker.run)

        self.worker.finished.connect(self.thread.quit)
        # basically lambda icon: a_btn.setIcon(icon)
        self.worker.finished.connect(self.set_icon)
        self.worker.finished.connect(self.worker.deleteLater)
        self.thread.finished.connect(self.thread.deleteLater)

        # Step 6: Start the thread
        logger.debug(
            f'Thread started at {(t1 := time.time())} seconds on thread {threading.get_ident()}')

        self.thread.start(priority=0)

        logger.debug(
            f'self.thread.isRunning() : {self.thread.isRunning()}, on thread {threading.get_ident()}')

    def set_icon(self):

        # print('set_icon')

        logger.debug('set_icon')

        app.quit()

        pass


if __name__ == "__main__":

    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    a = MyClass()
    sys.exit(app.exec())
```

output:

```
self.thread.isRunning() : False, on thread 139800282842944
Thread started at 1684857067.3460085 seconds on thread 139800282842944
self.thread.isRunning() : True, on thread 139800282842944
Worker started at 1684857067.3478193 seconds on thread 139798901659392
Worker finished @ 1684857067.3550224 seconds, 0.00721 seconds later
set_icon
```

Second one is based on [How to assign variables to worker Thread in Python PyQt5?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74348042/how-to-assign-variables-to-worker-thread-in-python-pyqt5) , code:

```
import sys

import logging

import threading

# from time import sleep

import time

from PyQt5.QtCore import QObject, QThread, pyqtSignal, Qt

from PyQt5.QtGui import QIcon

from PyQt5.QtWidgets import (
    QApplication,
    QLabel,
    QMainWindow,
    QPushButton,
    QVBoxLayout,
    QWidget,
)


logger = logging.getLogger("test")
logger.setLevel(level=logging.DEBUG)

logFileFormatter = logging.Formatter(
    fmt=f"%(levelname)s %(asctime)s (%(relativeCreated)d) \t %(pathname)s F%(funcName)s L%(lineno)s - %(message)s",
    datefmt="%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S",
)

console = logging.StreamHandler()
console.setLevel(logging.DEBUG)
logger.addHandler(console)


class Worker(QObject):
    finished = pyqtSignal(QIcon)

    def __init__(self, path=None):
        super(Worker, self).__init__()

        self.path = path

    def run(self):
        import threading
        logger.debug(
            f'Worker started at {(t1 := time.time())} seconds on thread {threading.get_ident()}')
        icon = QIcon()
        icon.addFile(self.path)
        logger.debug(
            f'Worker finished @ {time.time()} seconds, {(time.time() - t1):.3} seconds later')
        self.finished.emit(icon)


class MyClass(QObject):

    # All QObjects receive a parent argument (default to None)
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super(MyClass, self).__init__(parent)   # Call parent initializer.

        self.thumbnail_path = 'test.png'

        # Step 2: Create a QThread object
        self.thread = QThread()
        # Step 3: Create a worker object

        self.worker = Worker(self.thumbnail_path)

        # Step 4: Move worker to the thread
        self.worker.moveToThread(self.thread)

        logger.debug(
            f'self.thread.isRunning() : {self.thread.isRunning()}, on thread {threading.get_ident()}')

        # Step 5: Connect signals and slots
        # self.thread.started.connect(lambda: self.worker.run(self.thumbnail_path))

        self.thread.started.connect(self.worker.run)

        self.worker.finished.connect(self.thread.quit)
        # basically lambda icon: a_btn.setIcon(icon)
        self.worker.finished.connect(self.set_icon)
        self.worker.finished.connect(self.worker.deleteLater)
        self.thread.finished.connect(self.thread.deleteLater)

        # Step 6: Start the thread
        logger.debug(
            f'Thread started at {(t1 := time.time())} seconds on thread {threading.get_ident()}')

        self.thread.start(priority=0)

        logger.debug(
            f'self.thread.isRunning() : {self.thread.isRunning()}, on thread {threading.get_ident()}')

    def set_icon(self):

        # print('set_icon')

        logger.debug('set_icon')

        app.quit()

        pass


if __name__ == "__main__":

    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    a = MyClass()
    sys.exit(app.exec())
```

output:

```
self.thread.isRunning() : False, on thread 139884701431616
Thread started at 1684857105.0672066 seconds on thread 139884701431616
self.thread.isRunning() : True, on thread 139884701431616
Worker started at 1684857105.0705557 seconds on thread 139883385448192
Worker finished @ 1684857105.0839903 seconds, 0.0134 seconds later
set_icon
```

Third one I added Signals and Slots, code :

```
import sys

import logging

import threading

# from time import sleep

import time

from PyQt5.QtCore import QObject, QThread, pyqtSignal, pyqtSlot, Qt

from PyQt5.QtGui import QIcon

from PyQt5.QtWidgets import (
    QApplication,
    QLabel,
    QMainWindow,
    QPushButton,
    QVBoxLayout,
    QWidget,
)


logger = logging.getLogger("test")
logger.setLevel(level=logging.DEBUG)

logFileFormatter = logging.Formatter(
    fmt=f"%(levelname)s %(asctime)s (%(relativeCreated)d) \t %(pathname)s F%(funcName)s L%(lineno)s - %(message)s",
    datefmt="%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S",
)

console = logging.StreamHandler()
console.setLevel(logging.DEBUG)
logger.addHandler(console)


class Worker(QObject):
    finished = pyqtSignal(QIcon)

    @pyqtSlot(str)
    def run(self, n):

        print('n : ', n, type(n))

        import threading
        logger.debug(
            f'Worker started at {(t1 := time.time())} seconds on thread {threading.get_ident()}')
        icon = QIcon()
        # icon.addFile(n)
        logger.debug(
            f'Worker finished @ {time.time()} seconds, {(time.time() - t1):.3} seconds later')
        self.finished.emit(icon)


class MyClass(QMainWindow):

    work_requested = pyqtSignal(str)

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super(MyClass, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)

    # All QObjects receive a parent argument (default to None)
    # def __init__(self, parent=None):
    #     super(MyClass, self).__init__(parent)   # Call parent initializer.

        self.thumbnail_path = 'test.png'

        # Step 2: Create a QThread object
        self.thread = QThread()
        # Step 3: Create a worker object
        self.worker = Worker()

        # Step 4: Move worker to the thread
        self.worker.moveToThread(self.thread)

        logger.debug(
            f'self.thread.isRunning() : {self.thread.isRunning()}, on thread {threading.get_ident()}')

        # Step 5: Connect signals and slots
        # self.thread.started.connect(lambda: self.worker.run(self.thumbnail_path))

        self.work_requested.connect(self.worker.run)

        self.work_requested.emit('test.png')

        self.worker.finished.connect(self.thread.quit)
        # basically lambda icon: a_btn.setIcon(icon)
        self.worker.finished.connect(self.set_icon)
        self.worker.finished.connect(self.worker.deleteLater)
        self.thread.finished.connect(self.thread.deleteLater)

        # Step 6: Start the thread
        logger.debug(
            f'Thread started at {(t1 := time.time())} seconds on thread {threading.get_ident()}')

        self.thread.start(priority=0)

        logger.debug(
            f'self.thread.isRunning() : {self.thread.isRunning()}, on thread {threading.get_ident()}')

    def set_icon(self):

        # print('set_icon')

        logger.debug('set_icon')

        app.quit()

        pass


if __name__ == "__main__":

    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    a = MyClass()
    sys.exit(app.exec())
```

output:

```
self.thread.isRunning() : False, on thread 140092591085376
Thread started at 1684857172.9183104 seconds on thread 140092591085376
self.thread.isRunning() : True, on thread 140092591085376
Worker started at 1684857172.9207199 seconds on thread 140091345303296
Worker finished @ 1684857172.9222894 seconds, 0.00158 seconds later
set_icon
n :  test.png <class 'str'>
```

**Important note**

Used this approach to have a non GUI PyQt app : [Python PyQt: Is it possible to use QThread with a non-GUI program?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25392471/python-pyqt-is-it-possible-to-use-qthread-with-a-non-gui-program) , probably would have be better to use this answer : [How use PyQt without GUI?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30611290/how-use-pyqt-without-gui)

---

The [minimal-reproducible-example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) I started from is :

```
import sys

import logging

import threading

# from time import sleep

import time

from PyQt5.QtCore import QObject, QThread, pyqtSignal, Qt

from PyQt5.QtGui import QIcon

from PyQt5.QtWidgets import (
    QApplication,
    QLabel,
    QMainWindow,
    QPushButton,
    QVBoxLayout,
    QWidget,
)


logger = logging.getLogger("test")
logger.setLevel(level=logging.DEBUG)

logFileFormatter = logging.Formatter(
    fmt=f"%(levelname)s %(asctime)s (%(relativeCreated)d) \t %(pathname)s F%(funcName)s L%(lineno)s - %(message)s",
    datefmt="%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S",
)

console = logging.StreamHandler()
console.setLevel(logging.DEBUG)
logger.addHandler(console)


class Worker(QObject):
    finished = pyqtSignal(QIcon)

    def run(self, path: str):
        import threading
        logger.debug(
            f'Worker started at {(t1 := time.time())} seconds on thread {threading.get_ident()}')
        icon = QIcon()
        icon.addFile(path)
        logger.debug(
            f'Worker finished @ {time.time()} seconds, {(time.time() - t1):.3} seconds later')
        self.finished.emit(icon)


class MyClass(QObject):

    # All QObjects receive a parent argument (default to None)
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super(MyClass, self).__init__(parent)   # Call parent initializer.

        self.thumbnail_path = 'test.png'

        # Step 2: Create a QThread object
        self.thread = QThread()
        # Step 3: Create a worker object
        self.worker = Worker()
        # Step 4: Move worker to the thread
        self.worker.moveToThread(self.thread)

        logger.debug(
            f'self.thread.isRunning() : {self.thread.isRunning()}, on thread {threading.get_ident()}')

        # Step 5: Connect signals and slots
        # self.thread.started.connect(lambda: self.worker.run(self.thumbnail_path))

        self.thread.started.connect(lambda: self.worker.run(self.thumbnail_path))

        self.worker.finished.connect(self.thread.quit)
        # basically lambda icon: a_btn.setIcon(icon)
        self.worker.finished.connect(self.set_icon)
        self.worker.finished.connect(self.worker.deleteLater)
        self.thread.finished.connect(self.thread.deleteLater)

        # Step 6: Start the thread
        logger.debug(
            f'Thread started at {(t1 := time.time())} seconds on thread {threading.get_ident()}')

        self.thread.start(priority=0)

        logger.debug(
            f'self.thread.isRunning() : {self.thread.isRunning()}, on thread {threading.get_ident()}')

    def set_icon(self):

        logger.debug('set_icon')

        app.quit()

        pass


if __name__ == "__main__":

    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    a = MyClass()
    sys.exit(app.exec())
```

output:

```
self.thread.isRunning() : False, on thread 140687765116736
Thread started at 1684858090.5508475 seconds on thread 140687765116736
self.thread.isRunning() : True, on thread 140687765116736
Worker started at 1684858090.5602846 seconds on thread 140687765116736
Worker finished @ 1684858090.5662382 seconds, 0.00596 seconds later
set_icon
```

Answer (score 0):

this is not an answer but trying to show an example that is an MRE of something that works more or less like the OP question. I guess next step would be to have just one Long-Running Task button that would start  new thread every time is pushed ( taken from https://realpython.com/python-pyqt-qthread/ ):

```
import logging

import threading

import sys

from time import sleep

import time

from PyQt5.QtCore import QObject, QThread, pyqtSignal, Qt

from PyQt5.QtWidgets import (
    QApplication,
    QLabel,
    QMainWindow,
    QPushButton,
    QVBoxLayout,
    QWidget,
)

# Snip...


logger = logging.getLogger("test")
logger.setLevel(level=logging.DEBUG)

logFileFormatter = logging.Formatter(
    fmt=f"%(levelname)s %(asctime)s (%(relativeCreated)d) \t F%(funcName)s L%(lineno)s - %(message)s",
    datefmt="%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S",
)
fileHandler = logging.FileHandler(filename='test.log' , mode = 'w+')
fileHandler.setFormatter(logFileFormatter)
fileHandler.setLevel(level=logging.DEBUG)

console = logging.StreamHandler()
console.setLevel(logging.DEBUG)

logger.addHandler(fileHandler)
logger.addHandler(console)




# Step 1: Create a worker class
class Worker(QObject):
    finished = pyqtSignal()
    progress = pyqtSignal(int)

    def run(self):
        """Long-running task."""
        
        
        # import threading
        logger.debug(f'Worker started at {(t1 := time.time())} seconds on thread {threading.get_ident()}')
        
        
        for i in range(5):
            sleep(1)
            self.progress.emit(i + 1)
            
        logger.debug(f'Worker finished @ {time.time()} seconds, {(time.time() - t1):.3} seconds later on thread {threading.get_ident()}')

        self.finished.emit()

class Window(QMainWindow):

    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super().__init__(parent)
        self.clicksCount = 0
        self.setupUi()
        
    def setupUi(self):
        self.setWindowTitle("Freezing GUI")
        self.resize(300, 250)
        self.centralWidget = QWidget()
        self.setCentralWidget(self.centralWidget)
        # Create and connect widgets
        self.clicksLabel = QLabel("Counting: 0 clicks", self)
        self.clicksLabel.setAlignment(Qt.AlignHCenter | Qt.AlignVCenter)
        self.stepLabel = QLabel("Long-Running Step: 0")
        self.stepLabel.setAlignment(Qt.AlignHCenter | Qt.AlignVCenter)
        
        self.stepLabel2 = QLabel("Long-Running Step: 0")
        self.stepLabel2.setAlignment(Qt.AlignHCenter | Qt.AlignVCenter)
        
        
        self.countBtn = QPushButton("Click me!", self)
        self.countBtn.clicked.connect(self.countClicks)
        
        self.longRunningBtn = QPushButton("Long-Running Task!", self)
        self.longRunningBtn.clicked.connect(self.runLongTask)
        
        self.longRunningBtn2 = QPushButton("Long-Running Task!", self)
        self.longRunningBtn2.clicked.connect(self.runLongTask2)
        
        # Set the layout
        layout = QVBoxLayout()
        layout.addWidget(self.clicksLabel)
        layout.addWidget(self.countBtn)
        layout.addStretch()
        layout.addWidget(self.stepLabel)
        layout.addWidget(self.longRunningBtn)
        layout.addWidget(self.stepLabel2)
        layout.addWidget(self.longRunningBtn2)
        self.centralWidget.setLayout(layout)   
        
        print('main thread on : ', threading.get_ident())
        logger.debug(f'Main Thread started at {(t1 := time.time())} seconds on thread {threading.get_ident()}')
        
    def countClicks(self):
        self.clicksCount += 1
        self.clicksLabel.setText(f"Counting: {self.clicksCount} clicks")

    def reportProgress(self, n):
        self.stepLabel.setText(f"Long-Running Step: {n}")
        
    def reportProgress2(self, n):
        self.stepLabel2.setText(f"Long-Running Step: {n}")
        

    def runLongTask(self):
        # Step 2: Create a QThread object
        self.thread = QThread()
        # Step 3: Create a worker object
        self.worker = Worker()
        # Step 4: Move worker to the thread
        self.worker.moveToThread(self.thread)
        # Step 5: Connect signals and slots
        self.thread.started.connect(self.worker.run)
        self.worker.finished.connect(self.thread.quit)
        self.worker.finished.connect(self.worker.deleteLater)
        self.thread.finished.connect(self.thread.deleteLater)
        self.worker.progress.connect(self.reportProgress)

        # Step 6: Start the thread
        # self.thread.start()
        logger.debug(f'Thread started at {(t1 := time.time())} seconds on thread {threading.get_ident()}')
        self.thread.start(priority=0)

        # Final resets
        self.longRunningBtn.setEnabled(False)
        self.thread.finished.connect(
            lambda: self.longRunningBtn.setEnabled(True)
        )
        self.thread.finished.connect(
            lambda: self.stepLabel.setText("Long-Running Step: 0")
        )
        
    def runLongTask2(self):
        # Step 2: Create a QThread object
        self.thread2 = QThread()
        # Step 3: Create a worker object
        self.worker2 = Worker()
        # Step 4: Move worker to the thread
        self.worker2.moveToThread(self.thread2)
        # Step 5: Connect signals and slots
        self.thread2.started.connect(self.worker2.run)
        self.worker2.finished.connect(self.thread2.quit)
        self.worker2.finished.connect(self.worker2.deleteLater)
        self.thread2.finished.connect(self.thread2.deleteLater)
        self.worker2.progress.connect(self.reportProgress2)

        # Step 6: Start the thread
        # self.thread.start()
        logger.debug(f'Thread2 started at {(t1 := time.time())} seconds on thread {threading.get_ident()}')
        self.thread2.start(priority=0)

        # Final resets
        self.longRunningBtn2.setEnabled(False)
        self.thread2.finished.connect(
            lambda: self.longRunningBtn2.setEnabled(True)
        )
        self.thread2.finished.connect(
            lambda: self.stepLabel2.setText("Long-Running2 Step: 0")
        )

if __name__ == "__main__":
    
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    win = Window()
    win.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec())
```

output, logging file:

```
Main Thread started at 1684097271.8644187 seconds on thread 140012231251776
main thread on :  140012231251776
Thread started at 1684097273.363497 seconds on thread 140012231251776
Worker started at 1684097273.3651009 seconds on thread 140010737583872
Thread2 started at 1684097275.1072826 seconds on thread 140012231251776
Worker started at 1684097275.1093683 seconds on thread 140010729191168
Worker finished @ 1684097278.3725977 seconds, 5.01 seconds later on thread 140010737583872
Worker finished @ 1684097280.1210995 seconds, 5.01 seconds later on thread 140010729191168
Thread started at 1684097284.508442 seconds on thread 140012231251776
Worker started at 1684097284.512356 seconds on thread 140010729191168
Thread2 started at 1684097285.267206 seconds on thread 140012231251776
Worker started at 1684097285.2695184 seconds on thread 140010737583872
Worker finished @ 1684097289.5649338 seconds, 5.05 seconds later on thread 140010729191168
Worker finished @ 1684097290.290237 seconds, 5.02 seconds later on thread 140010737583872
```

just press one of the two Long-Running Task to start a new thread.

Using `QThreadPool`  as per https://www.pythonguis.com/tutorials/multithreading-pyqt-applications-qthreadpool/

```
import logging

import threading

import sys

from time import sleep

import time

from PyQt5.QtCore import QObject, QThreadPool, pyqtSignal, pyqtSlot, Qt, QRunnable

from PyQt5.QtWidgets import (
    QApplication,
    QLabel,
    QMainWindow,
    QPushButton,
    QVBoxLayout,
    QWidget,
)

# Snip...


logger = logging.getLogger("test")
logger.setLevel(level=logging.DEBUG)

logFileFormatter = logging.Formatter(
    fmt=f"%(levelname)s %(asctime)s (%(relativeCreated)d) \t F%(funcName)s L%(lineno)s - %(message)s",
    datefmt="%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S",
)
fileHandler = logging.FileHandler(filename='test.log' , mode = 'w+')
fileHandler.setFormatter(logFileFormatter)
fileHandler.setLevel(level=logging.DEBUG)

console = logging.StreamHandler()
console.setLevel(logging.DEBUG)

logger.addHandler(fileHandler)
logger.addHandler(console)




# Step 1: Create a worker class
class Worker(QRunnable):
    
    def __init__(self, n):
        super(Worker, self).__init__()
        self.n = n

    @pyqtSlot()
    def run(self):
        
        logger.debug(f'Worker {self.n} started at {(t1 := time.time())} seconds on thread {threading.get_ident()}')
        
        time.sleep(5)
        
        logger.debug(f'Worker {self.n} finished @ {time.time()} seconds, {(time.time() - t1):.3} seconds later on thread {threading.get_ident()}')


class Window(QMainWindow):

    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super().__init__(parent)
        self.clicksCount = 0
        
        self.n = 1
        
        self.threadpool = QThreadPool()
        
        print("Multithreading with maximum %d threads" % self.threadpool.maxThreadCount())
        
        self.setupUi()
        
        
    def setupUi(self):
        self.setWindowTitle("Freezing GUI")
        self.resize(300, 250)
        self.centralWidget = QWidget()
        self.setCentralWidget(self.centralWidget)
        # Create and connect widgets
        self.clicksLabel = QLabel("Counting: 0 clicks", self)
        self.clicksLabel.setAlignment(Qt.AlignHCenter | Qt.AlignVCenter)
        self.stepLabel = QLabel("Long-Running Task: " + str(self.n))
        self.stepLabel.setAlignment(Qt.AlignHCenter | Qt.AlignVCenter)
        
       
        self.countBtn = QPushButton("Click me!", self)
        self.countBtn.clicked.connect(self.countClicks)
        
        self.longRunningBtn = QPushButton("Long-Running Task!", self)
        self.longRunningBtn.clicked.connect(lambda : self.runLongTask(self.n))
        

        # Set the layout
        layout = QVBoxLayout()
        layout.addWidget(self.clicksLabel)
        layout.addWidget(self.countBtn)
        layout.addStretch()
        layout.addWidget(self.stepLabel)
        layout.addWidget(self.longRunningBtn)

        self.centralWidget.setLayout(layout)   
        
        print('main thread on : ', threading.get_ident())
        logger.debug(f'Main Thread started at {(t1 := time.time())} seconds on thread {threading.get_ident()}')
        
     def countClicks(self):
        self.clicksCount += 1
        self.clicksLabel.setText(f"Counting: {self.clicksCount} clicks")


    def runLongTask(self, n):
        
        self.stepLabel.setText(f"Long-Running Step: {n}")
        
        worker = Worker(n)
        
        self.threadpool.start(worker)
        
        self.n = n +1
        


if __name__ == "__main__":
    
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    win = Window()
    win.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec())
```

output / logging file:

```
Main Thread started at 1684100478.011803 seconds on thread 140273846236992
Multithreading with maximum 2 threads
main thread on :  140273846236992
Worker 1 started at 1684100481.7684858 seconds on thread 140272195036928
Worker 2 started at 1684100482.0010214 seconds on thread 140272186644224
Worker 1 finished @ 1684100486.7727013 seconds, 5.0 seconds later on thread 140272195036928
Worker 3 started at 1684100486.7735689 seconds on thread 140272195036928
Worker 2 finished @ 1684100487.005124 seconds, 5.0 seconds later on thread 140272186644224
Worker 4 started at 1684100487.0061054 seconds on thread 140272186644224
Worker 3 finished @ 1684100491.7825654 seconds, 5.01 seconds later on thread 140272195036928
Worker 5 started at 1684100491.785199 seconds on thread 140272195036928
Worker 4 finished @ 1684100492.0294738 seconds, 5.02 seconds later on thread 140272186644224
Worker 5 finished @ 1684100496.834566 seconds, 5.05 seconds later on thread 140272195036928
```

just keep clicking the **Long-Running Task** button as long as you want, keep in mind that the number of threads are related to your CPU as per : `QThreadPool().maxThreadCount()` ; but in any case it will take care of the queque.